# Set "visible" property in RadzenDataGrid column based on value of the entire property of the object

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, radzen

I have a radzen datagrid that receives a `IEnumerable<T>` and displays a set of columns

```
<RadzenDataGrid AllowSorting="true" AllowColumnReorder="true"  AllowMultiColumnSorting="true"  PageSize="40" AllowFiltering="true" FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" Data="@FilteredList" TItem="Employee" AllowPaging="true" PagerHorizontalAlign="HorizontalAlign.Left" ShowPagingSummary="true">
        <Columns>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Employee" Property="EmployeeName" Title="Employee Name"  Visible="@ShowColumn" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Employee" Property="EmployeeNumber" Title="Employee Number" Sortable="false" Width="125px"  TextAlign="TextAlign.Center"/>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Employee" Property="EmployeeType" Title="Employee Type" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" />
        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>
```

(simplified datagrid for brevity)

Now, the `IEnumerable<Employee>` that the `RadzenDataGrid` component receives is not always the same, based on previous conditions, let's say it can receive one that has all `EmployeeName` in `null` or can have all EmployeeType in null, so, what I want to do is to set the bool value of visible property of `RadzenDataGrid` to be a depending if there are values in the property of the object that receives.

I have set the `RadzenDataGridColumn` with the property `Visible="@ShowColumn"` but I don't know how I should do the method so it will calculate this `bool` for each `RadzenDataGridColumn` and I'm not entirely sure if it should go on the component page, or the parent that calls the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the @code section, at some point you need to populate FilteredList. I think thats the point where you can calculate that bool variable. Maybe with a simple LINQ line:

```
{
    FilteredList = PopulateFromDataStore();
    var showName = FilteredList.Any(e => e.Name != null);
}
```

That way, if ANY of the employees has value on his Name property, you show that column.